# The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/chart_js.js?v=425f86ec' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, chart.js, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using Sveltekit and I upgraded chart.js from @2.9.4 to its latest version, upon upgrading I get the below error:

```
500
The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/chart_js.js?v=425f86ec' does not provide an export named 'default'
SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/chart_js.js?v=425f86ec' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I get above stated error as I import it as below:

```
import chartjs from 'chart.js';
```

I also get the same error in any version above chart.js@2.9.4.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.js V3 is treeshakable so you need to import and register everything or if you want everything you need to import the chart from the auto import like so:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

For more information about the different ways of importing and using chart.js you can read the [integration page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/getting-started/integration.html) in the docs.

Since you are upgrading from Chart.js V2 you might also want to read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/getting-started/v3-migration.html) since there are some major breaking changes between V2 and V3